# Hide URL id from parameter string react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I created dynamic routes based on an id param passed to my react route. But, I would like the url to show as follows: "projects/:id=projectname"
But I would like to hide the ":id=" part of the string. How can I achieve this?

My code below:

Link to direct to the routes:

```
<Link to = {{pathname: `${PROJECT}=${props.projectDetails.id}`, state: {projectDetails: props.projectDetails}}}/>
```

Route defined:

```
Route exact path = "/projects/:id" component = {Project} drawerOpen = {this.state.drawerOpen} toggleDrawer = {this.toggleDrawer}/>
```

The route component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import DashboardLayout from '../components/dashboardLayout';
import * as Constants from '../common/constants'
import { setCurrentProject } from '../store/project/projectActions';
import '../styles/app.css'

class Project extends Component {
  constructor( props ) {
    super( props )
      this.state = {
      listItems: ["Home", "Projects"],
      theme: Constants.darkTheme,
      formModalOpen: false,
      alertModalOpen: false,
      deleteAlertActive: false,
      domainUsers: [],
      currentProject: props.location.state.projectDetails,
      value: 0
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.dispatch( setCurrentProject(this.props.location.state.projectDetails) )
  }

  render() {
    return (
    <div>
      <DashboardLayout
        appState = {this.state.currentProject.id}
        isOpen = {this.props.drawerOpen}
        toggleDrawer = {this.props.toggleDrawer}
        menuItems = {this.state.listItems}
        listItemClicked = {this.setTitle}/>
    </div> 
    );
  }
}

export default Project;
```

Answer (score 3):

In a simple way: You don't need to pass `id` to your Route's path. Create route without `id` and pass `id` as a prop to your `Project` component.

```
<Route exact path="/project" render={() => (<Project id={id} />)} />
```

Or you can pass it as a state prop in `Link` component.

```
<Link
  to={{
    pathname: `${PROJECT}`,
    state: {
      projectDetails: props.projectDetails,
      id: id // id you want to get in Project component
    }
  }}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears as though you are conflating a route's `match.params` for an URL's query parameters. You've defined your route path to be `path = "/projects/:id"`, which means your URLs should look like "/projects/someProjectId", without *any* query parameters.

You send the id both in the match params, i.e. `props.match.params` and in the route state, i.e. `props.location.state.projectDetails.id`. Just access it in the receiving component off the route props.

Also, construct the URL correctly, `${PROJECT}/${props.projectDetails.id}` versus `${PROJECT}=${props.projectDetails.id}`.

```
<Link
  to={{
    pathname: `${PROJECT}/${props.projectDetails.id}`, // assumes PROJECT resolves to "/projects"
    state: {
      projectDetails: props.projectDetails,
    },
  }}
/>
```